# How to import azure app configuration to local visual studio?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, azure-configuration

This might be a silly question.

I have an azure web app and an azure function app running. Both are written in .net

I want to debug the application in the local visual studio with the configuration values from the Azure portal.

How can I download the azure configuration for the web app service and function to use in local VS? Manually copying takes a lot of time and is error-prone.

Directly copying using advanced editing is not giving configuration in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on this, I found a way by exporting app service configuration to app configuration store and then exporting from there to local file.

There is an import/export option in the App configuration store for each app configuration you created.

Goto `Import/export` , choose your `source and target` locations and click on apply as shown:

[image]

Imported keys and values from Azure App service to app configuration first and then import from app configuration store to local file in `json` format.

[image]

[image]

*Retrieved key-values to local folder:*

[image]

You can also use `Az CLI` command to export configuration from Azure app service.

```bash
az appconfig kv export --name <Appconfiguration> --appservice-account <appservice> -d file --path "C:\temp\filename.json" --format json
```

[image]

Alternatively, You can read configuration from the App configuration store by using builder configuration code as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core6x).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in my case, I don't have a separate app configuration store, the configurations are part of the application's (function app's) configuration.

Comment: You can also import the configuration from the function app directly using the above given command. @Vish